# How to validate for syntax of a coded file in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Just like how IDEs behave, I have to do that in javascript for a web application.

Only thing I want to track is if user has correctly opened and closed the curly braces. If at all there is a missing brace, I want to highlight that line somehow to make user aware that one of the braces is missing.

I tried searching, but couldn't get much pointers or hints around this.

For example, the coded file (in a textarea) can be like this:

```
function(){
  if() {
     {
     }
  }

}

function(){
}
```

Kindly let me know how can this be achieved.

Comment: why not jslint/jshint/eslint?

Comment: take a look at this http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Comment: Thanks Vipin, yes that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have JavaScript itself parse (but not run) the code by passing the string into `new Function` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)):

```
try {
    new Function(theString);
    console.log("Parsed successfully.");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Parsing error");
}
```

That just gives you a very high-level indication (good/bad), and only works for code that's valid within a function (so, not for something designed for module scope using `import` or `export`).

For anything more, you'd need a parser. If you [search for "JavaScript parser"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=JavaScript%20parser) you'll find several options, hopefully one of them will suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I looked for javascript parser and Esprima seems to do the job for me. Cheers!